# I don't want to debug my SPFx ListView Command Extension in production

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, spfx-extensions

I have an SPFx solution with a ListView Command Extension.  I ran the following to create the .sppkg file for deployment to production:

> gulp build
>
> gulp bundle --ship
>
> gulp package-solution --ship

I install and deploy the solution and then add my new client side solution App in my desired site collection.  When I open a document library (to which the ListView Command Extension applies) I get this "Error loading debug manifests" error:
[image]

I don't want to debug my solution in production. What am I missing?  Why is it trying to load debug manifests?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your solution script is loading from your local,run gulp serve to start your local server so your webpart could load the script.

To deploy the solution to product, enable CDN in your tenant so the solution script could be hosted in CDN.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/hosting-extension-from-office365-cdn

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The tenant CDN was already enabled. And my project was configured as instructed in the tutorial you sent.  Without changing anything, my ListView Command Set extension is now working as expected.  I don't know why--maybe some problem with updating or adding/deploying the app in the app catalog or in running the gulp tasks.  I don't know, but it is working now.